# Combining multiple IF statements together in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

```
=IFS(AND(OR(C15="Approved",D15="Approved",E15="Approved",B15="Approved"),B15="Rejected")," ")

=IF(AND(OR(C15="Approved",D15="Approved",E15="Approved",B15="Approved"),B15="Approved"),"Approved","Rejected")

=IF(AND(B15="Rejected",C15="Rejected",D15="Rejected",E15="Rejected"),"Rejected","Approved")

=IF(AND(AND(C15="Rejected",D15="Rejected",E15="Rejected"),B18="Approved"),"Rejected","Approved")
```

These are the four formulas we need to be in one cell. Based on the following:

- If B rejected, and one of C-E approved = blank
- If B approved, and one of C-E approved = approved
- If B-E all rejected = rejected
- If B approved and C-E rejected = rejected

[image]

We need all of these conditions to function together in one cell. How can I combine these 4 IF formulas together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C2:E2,"Approved")=0,"Rejected",IF(B2="Rejected","","Approved"))
```

A brief explanation:

`COUNTIF(C2:E2,"Approved")`, counts the number of cells in `C2:E2` whose value is "Approved". If the count is `0` then obviously all of them are "Rejected", hence the formula will return "Rejected" (value of `B2` is irrelevant in this case). If the count is not `0` then obviously at least one of them must be "Approved", in which case we check the value of `B2` to determine if the formula should return "Approved" or ""

Comment: Hi cybernetic.nomad, your response was very helpful. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I realized I forgot to mention the criteria below and I am having trouble adding it to your solution.


If B2 is blank and C2:E2 has any combination of Approved/Rejected then leave cell blank


If B2:E2 are all blank then leave cell blank


Thanks in advance for helping me add these criteria to your original solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND(OR(C15="Approved",D15="Approved",E15="Approved",B15="Approved"),B15="Rejected"),,
 IF(AND(OR(C15="Approved",D15="Approved",E15="Approved",B15="Approved"),B15="Approved"),"Approved",
 IF(AND(B15="Rejected",C15="Rejected",D15="Rejected",E15="Rejected"),"Rejected",
 IF(AND(AND(C15="Rejected",D15="Rejected",E15="Rejected"),B18="Approved"),"Rejected",))))
```